# visual studio find and replace highlight color

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is there a way to change the highlight color when something is found with the find and replace in visual studio? Right now I have a white background and it highlights to light gray when it finds something which is not much help.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Absolutely! Tools -> Options ->  Environment -> Fonts and Colors -> Find Highlight (Extension)[image]

Comment: I don't have a find highlight. Where can I find that extension?

Comment: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/

Comment: I installed that extension and I still cant find the Find Highlight extension thing in the fonts and colors but it is now that yellow like on yours so that is good enough. Thanks!!

Comment: If you have Productivity Power Tools installed then 'Find Highlight (Extension)' will modify the background color but not the foreground. The foreground color will remain the color it normally is with syntax highlighting.

Comment: Mine says "Highlighted reference" instead, maybe that's it?

Comment: I would like to see this work without the Productivity Power Tools because I don't like the QuickSearch feature you have to enable in order to achieve the find-result highlighting with this solution. If you disable the QuickSearch, the highlighting goes away.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2013 Options > **Environment** > Fonts and Color

Answer (score 34):

Go to Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and colors and also change to color of 'Inactive Selected Text' which can be used for searching CSS or html. This fixed the issue for me. :)

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. I shouldn't need an extension to change the highlight color. Thanks :)

Comment: I switched it to black just to see what it would do... it darkened the color, but didn't make it black. This works good enough for me, but I wonder if the extension gives you the ability to choose an exact color or if it just _influences_ the color as it appears this method does.

Answer (score 10):

In Visual Studio 2015, you can try

`Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors -> Find Match Highlight`

[image: Find Match Highlight]

Comment: Also in VS17. But why is foreground disabled?

Comment: @SteveM.Bay It seems like the foreground color is stuck in black for some reason. I'm not sure about it though...

Comment: Does anyone have a good color with the dark theme? I tried a few and strings (which are brown by default) aren’t really readable. And if I choose a color where the text is readable I have real problems to see where the highlight is.

Comment: @J3soon The foreground is not stuck. It is the same color as it was without highlighting. Different elements of code have different foreground color.

Answer (score 8):

Try to look at `Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors > Selected Text` (should be something like that, my Visual Studio isn't in English...).

Comment: I confirm it is `Selected Text` in english.

Answer (score 3):

I am using Visual Studio 2017. When **Quick Find** or **Quick Replace** box is open,

[image: Quick Find box]

all the matches of the text in the document are highlighted. The color of the *selected* match is a combination of the **selected-text color** and the **highlighted-match color**. I do not know how to change the former (which is annoying), but you can modify the latter( like in the answer by @J3soon), and thus indirectly modify the color of the selected match.

> Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors -> Find Match
>   Highlight

[image: Fonts and Colors options]

Answer (score 1):

I installed [Productivity Power Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef) and then the missing *Find Highlight (extension)* font shows up.

I downloaded it, opened it, closed VS 2010, opened VS 2010, went to `Tools-> Options...-> Environment-> Fonts and Colors-> Display items:-> Find Highlight (Extension)` and the color was green for current find and yellow for all the other finds instead of that barley visible `light light light light blue or grey (229R, 235G, 241B)` for current find and nothing for other finds.

Another thing I did before I installed the PPT was did a find then esc out of the find box then used F3 and the color was a reasonable light blue.

Answer (score 0):

Its "Find Scope Highlight" in VS 2012!