# What's the vs.net 2010 color item name for highlighted text when searching?

Tags: visual-studio, colors

Whenever I do a find/replace in vs.net 2010, I can barely see where the highlighted text is on y screen.

I want to change the background color of the highlighted text during find/replace etc.

In vs.net settings (font and colors), what is the item name that is for the highlighted text during find/replace?

Comment: Are you talking about the Productivity Power Tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within Visual Studio 2010 
menu: Tools->Options->Environment->Fonts and Colors

in the Selected Items window: choose "Selected Text" (it's the second from the top for me.)
You can then change the background color (on the right side of the dialog window.)

Answer (score 2):

The correct item is inactive selected text.

Answer (score 1):

See Dave's answer here:
[visual studio find and replace highlight color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7192536/visual-studio-find-and-replace-highlight-color)

You have to install the Productivity Power Tools extension to change this setting. Then it will be under Find Highlight (Extension).

For me, the selected text setting does not affect the color of highlighting when doing a find/replace or a quick find.

Answer (score 0):

You'll find that one at: **Text Editor -> Selected Text**.  You're looking to set the **Item Background** property.  Be aware, it's the same format used for any time text is selected, not just when find/replace is invoked -- that specific action doesn't have a specific format associated with it.