# Disable the selection highlight in RichTextBox or TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, selection, richtextbox

How can I disable the selection highlight of `RichTexBox` or `TextBox` in my Windows Forms Application as shown in the image.

[image]

I need to change selection highlight color from `Blue` to `White`, because I need to hide selection in `TextBox` or `RichTextBox` all the time. I tried to use `RichTextBox.HideSelection = true`, but it doesn't not work as I expect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [visual studio find and replace highlight color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7192536/visual-studio-find-and-replace-highlight-color)

Comment: thank you for your ans but i need to do in richtextbox

Comment: how about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183599/rich-text-box-how-to-highlight-text-block

Comment: You are probably looking for [RichTextBox.SelectionBackColor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectionbackcolor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: thank you but RichTextBox.SelectionBackColor can't solve my problem

Comment: i need to change cursor  highlight Color not a background font color

Comment: @wong what do you mean by cursor highlight color?

Comment: @active92 sorry if my english is not good 
i mean when you click mouse down for select character or string in richtextbox the color is "blue" i need to change color blue to another color

Comment: @wong i get what you mean now but I don't think that is something that you can change in your code. it has to do with you visual studio's settings.

Comment: set the control's `.SelectionColor = Color.Black` or the color you want; Before that set the `SelectionStart` to 0 and `SelectionLength` to the `Length` of the text in the control

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can handle [`WM_SETFOCUS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646283(v=vs.85).aspx) message of `RichTextBox` and replace it with [`WM_KILLFOCUS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646282(v=vs.85).aspx).

In the following code, I've created a `ExRichTextBox` class having `Selectable` property:

- `Selectable`: Enables or disables selection highlight. If you set `Selectable` to `false` then the selection highlight will be disabled. It's enabled by default.

Remarks: It doesn't make the control read-only and if you need to make it read-only, you should also set `ReadOnly` property to `true` and its `BackColor` to `White`.

```
public class ExRichTextBox : RichTextBox
{
    public ExRichTextBox()
    {
        Selectable = true;
    }
    const int WM_SETFOCUS = 0x0007;
    const int WM_KILLFOCUS = 0x0008;

    ///<summary>
    /// Enables or disables selection highlight. 
    /// If you set `Selectable` to `false` then the selection highlight
    /// will be disabled. 
    /// It's enabled by default.
    ///</summary>
    [DefaultValue(true)]
    public bool Selectable { get; set; }
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_SETFOCUS && !Selectable)
            m.Msg = WM_KILLFOCUS;

        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

You can do the same for `TextBox` control.

Comment: Works like magic. I would change the code example so `Selectable` will be false...

Comment: @Sipo Good to hear! The reason that I set it to true by default, was because I didn't want to change the default behavior of the `RichtextBox` unless you set the `Selectable` to `false` intentionally.

Comment: Thanks for the quick comment! I think that because the default behavior is exactly what the OP **doesn't** want it would be more suitable...

Comment: @Sipo Thanks for the feedback. I see, I edited the answer a bit, to make it clearer that, to disable selection you need to set the `Selectable` property to `false`.