# How can I stop the user being able to edit text in a richtextbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I have a short section of code which dynamically adds a richtextbox to each cell of a tablelayoutpanel, but the user shouldn't be able to edit the text inside.

```
RichTextBox[,] textList = new RichTextBox[4, 4];
            for (int a = 0; a < 4; a++)
            {
                for (int b = 0; b < 4; b++)
                {
                    RichTextBox newBox = new RichTextBox { Dock = DockStyle.Fill, Text = "2", BackColor = Color.AntiqueWhite, BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None, SelectionAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center, Font = new Font("Arial", 36, FontStyle.Bold), SelectionProtected = true };
                    textList[a, b] = newBox;
                    tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(newBox, a, b);
                }
            }
```

I have tried using SelectionProtected = true, but it doesn't prevent the user clicking on and editing the text, and Enabled = true makes the text appear greyed out.

Comment: I think you mean `Enabled = false` in the last sentence.

Comment: Setting `Enabled = false` prevents the control to respond to user interaction. You cannot copy the text, for instance. Use the `ReadOnly` property.

Answer (score 4):

You can set  `ReadOnly` property to `true`:

```cs
newBox.ReadOnly = true;
textList[a, b] = newBox;
```

See [TextBoxBase.ReadOnly Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.readonly?view=windowsdesktop-7.0)

Comment: ReadOnly = true works great for stopping the user from editing the text, thank you. Is there any way I can also stop them selecting it? I can still click on the textboxes to make a blinking bar appear.

Comment: @forefie: You can  use the `SelectionChanged()`  event handler of the `RichTextBox` and set `SelectionLength = 0;` or see the following post: [Disable the selection highlight in RichTextBox or TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39592157/6630084)